# Salesforce API design patterns

Tags: rest-api, api, design-patterns, mulesoft

we are moving away from point to point integrations to Mule(API Led integration ) and are in the process of revamping our endpoints and thus having all the endpoints pass through mule anypoint , this is to enable and bring in lot of advantages that we have with ESB and also decouple or apis with external systems.

Would like to know if there are any design patterns that i could leverage/implement as part of architecture revamp ,since we would be moving lot of desearilization/transformations etc to mule and keep business logic in salesforce .

any wrappers /delegators etc kind of patterns that i can use , i know there should exist something that most of architects might have used but i unable to connect pieces.

External Client -> Mule Endpoint -> Salesforce API Wrapper -> Delegator -> business Later -> DML layer  , it would be of great help if someone could help me give a live example of their implementation that i could use , key takeaways that i am looking for as part of these design

1. separation of sphagetti code out there , all business logic,dmls,rules etc lie in same class.
2. minimum rework when a business logic changes
3. may be something that can be packaged and deployed in other orgs etc